# Getting a count of angular repeater matches by attribute?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a table built in AngularJS 1.35 and a JSON file with 100 users.  Th users have attributes such as group, phone, location, etc.

In this particular table, I wanted to parse the JSON file for all the groups the users are in, and filter the unique values.  I was able to the using angular ui utilities' "unique" filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users.users | unique:'group'">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="user.selected"></td>
    <td>{{user.group}}</td>
    <td>number of users in this group?</td>        
</tr>
```

I now have a list of the groups. I want to print, in the row for each group, the number of matches to that group.

In other words, I need a table such as:

```
| new york -|- 20 users |
| dallas   -|- 10 users |
```

etc.

Comment: You can chain multiple filters in angular, eg you can write a custom sum filter

Comment: I know about chaining filters, but here I don't want or need to filter the result set; i want to print out, in the row for each group, the number of matches to that group.

Comment: Unclear what you have tried; reads like a "do my work for me" question.

Comment: i am trying things such as `<td width="300">{{users | filter:{group:user.group} }}</td>   ` which still gets me all the users.  I am unclear on he sometimes arcane syntax of the filter.

Comment: I've tried making a plunkr, but I ca't get the ui uilities to run (the unique filter)  http://plnkr.co/edit/w8WZ8Ydy6xUp4XZdHeP5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `count` filter and apply it to the filtered lists:

```
app.filter('count', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.length;
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<td width="300">{{users | filter:{group:user.group} | count}}</td>
```

See it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nLJFQ0qj5BUECA5hl6Zx?p=preview).